# Почему при пустом словаре выходит ошибка KeyError: 2?

Tags: python

```
def update_dictionary(d, key, value):
    if key in d:
        d[key] += [value]
    else:
        d[key * 2] += [value]


d = {}
(update_dictionary(d, 1, -1))
print(d)
```

Comment: Кст, а зачем круглые скобки вокруг вызова функции? :) Это не нужно делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что, для оператора `+=` нужно взять значение из словаря, чтобы произвести сложение в:

```
d[key * 2] += [value]
```

Т.е. оно на самом деле будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
d[key * 2] = d[key * 2] + [value]
```

##### Думаю, нужно просто присвоить по ключу:

```
d[key * 2] = [value]
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался

Comment: @user2473478422, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)